# Transfer of PHP object via $_POST by echo

Tags: php, forms, object

How do you transfer a PHP object through a form submit? I am unsure about how serialization works as I have not done it before and the explanations of how to handle the string have not made sense to me. I have tried using a session but this did not work either.

```
$selected_student = $_POST['selected_student']; 

$students = $teacher->getStudents($teacher->teacherId);
?>

<form id = "select_student" method = 'POST' action = "<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"> 
 <?php
      foreach($students as $studentObject)
              {  
               ?><li><b><?php echo $studentObject->studentFullName;?><b><input type = "hidden" id = "student_identifier" name = "student_identifier" value = '<?php echo $studentObject;  ?>'></li><?php
              }          
 ?>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['student_identifier']))
{
 ?>
  <input type ="text" readonly name = "student_first_name" id = "student_first_name" value = "<?php echo $selected_student->studentFirstName;  ?>">
  <input type="text" readonly name = "student_last_name" id = "student_last_name" value = "<?php echo $selected_student->studentLastName;  ?>">
<?php
}
?>
```

Student Class

```
class Student {

 public  $studentFirstName;
 public  $studentLastName;
 public  $studentFullName;
 public  $studentUsername;
 public  $studentEmail;
 public  $studentSchool;
 public  $studentDetails;
 public  $studentDoB;

}
```

Teacher Class, function getStudents ()

```
function getStudents ($teacher_id) {

$teacher_students = [];
$dbc= connectDb();
 $stmt=$dbc->query("SELECT student.firstname, student.lastname, student.username, student.dob, student.school, student.email FROM student INNER JOIN teacher ON teacher.id=$teacher_id INNER JOIN junction_student_teacher ON junction_student_teacher.student_id=student.id"); 

  while($row = $stmt->fetch())
  {
    $student = new Student();   

     $firstName = $row['firstname'];
      $lastName = $row['lastname'];
       $name = $firstName . ' ' . $lastName;

     $student->studentFirstName=$firstName;
      $student->studentLastName=$lastName;
       $student->studentFullName=$name;
        $student->studentEmail=$row['email'];
         $student->studentSchool=$row['school'];
          $student->studentDoB=$row['dob'];
           $student->studentUsername=$row['username'];

    $teacher_students[] = $student;

  }

 return $teacher_students;

}
```

Java script

```
$('li').click(function() 
{
  $('li').css({"background-color": "#F7F7F7"});
    $(this).css({"background-color": "red" });

   var  selectedStudent = $(this).text();

    // Remove saved data from sessionStorage
    sessionStorage.removeItem('selectedStudent');
    //store the new value
    sessionStorage.setItem('selectedStudent', selectedStudent);

    $('#select_student').submit();
});
```

Comment: No you can't. Only scalar values to be transferred via HTTP request. Serialization will work but it makes the problem more complex. Example: manage/sync properties in client/server. Best practice is transferring the identifier with its data in separated fields

Comment: Could a session be used to transfer the object or is that just a worse way of serializing what could be transmitted via a form with hidden fields?